# How to include Windows.h with rust bindgen?

Tags: c++, rust, rust-bindgen

I am starting a new addon for MSFS2020 in rust with the SimConnect SDK written in c++. I am using the bingen crates to create the binding with the SDK.

I need to include Windows.h for the binding to work but I get the following error:

```
error: header 'Windows.h' does not exist.
```

If I create a simple c++ project on Visual Studio I can successfully include this header so it's definitely there, but I did not succeed to add it in my rust build.

How can I make my rust build find this header and successfully bind the sdk?

Notes:

1. I installed the c++ toolchain with Visual Studio 2022
2. I installed the LLVM toolchain and added the LIBCLANG_PATH to the LLVM bin folder in my environment variables

Comment: Looking into it... For now I'm back with the error that pushed into adding the "windows.h": error: unknown type name 'DWORD'. Any idea for this error?

Comment: I found a repo that uses this method: https://github.com/rylev/msfs2020 and seems to be workign..

Comment: No problem, I contacted the author of the repo but I haven't add any answer yet. I'm sure the solution is dumb as hell but my knowledge in c++ build tools is limited.

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from access right rules. Running `cargo build` as an administrator worked perfectly.